# Force clients browser cache to clear for php generated pages

Tags: wordpress, caching, cookies, browser, progressive-web-apps

I have been searching the web for a while now, looking for a solution how to force a client's browser to not only clear cached JS and CSS files, but also php generated files? Or maybe it has something to do with the cookie handling...?

My current situation: I am maintaining a custom WordPress Theme and have written a filter function to change the html output for the password form for password protected posts. When applying the changes and changing the theme version, the html output is updated as expected. However, when trying to enter the password the user is then logged out from the website instead of accessing the post...

Opening an incognito tab or clearing the browser cache resolves the issue and everything works as it should. However, I cannot contact all the users and explain to them how to clear their browser cache! Especially since I regularly need to make similar changes on the site as new features are added while it is already in use.

Also noteworthy: the website runs with SuperPWA and most users access the site via an installed version of the PWA on their mobile devices. So disabling this plugin is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose on JS / CSS I use the 'Prevent Browser Caching' plugin and it works great.
About clearing generated PHP... Are you using a caching plugin? Remove it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the assets' Cache-Control header value to control how long a network request is cached by the browser.

If you cache an asset using the service worker then you need to create an invalidation routine that works for your site. There are multiple cache invalidation strategies you can employ. I use a variety of these in the applications I develop.

Comment: But would changing the headers force the client's browser to clear assets which were already cached?

I am still very new to the world of service workers and since this is handled by a third party plugin, I'm not sure how much influence I can have here...?

Comment: Cache-Control tell user agents, routers, etc max suggested times to cache a resource. Yes, generally speaking you will have them invalidate the cache and fetch from the network when the time to live expires.
As for service workers you are in complete control of how long an asset or data is cached, unless the device purges it early to free up disk space.

Comment: So from what I understand, the files cached by the service worker or the expiry time set within the service worker would prevent a call to check if the Cache-Control headers were changed, until the expiry date set by the service worker is reached, correct? In this case my only option would be to manually adjust the service worker and it's caching policies? However, this is built into a third party plugin and I would hate to tamper with it's core files or even begin to understand how it works in detail...